# Slickgrid highlighting not happening

Tags: slickgrid

I have a grid made using slickgrid on a html page. I want to highlight certain cells.

I have added this at the head section of html

```
  <style>
  .changed{ background: yellow } 

  </style>
```

I have this as the options:

```
var options = {
                    enableCellNavigation: true,
                    enableColumnReorder: false,
                    cellHighlightCssClass: "changed",
                };
```

And this is how the grid is getting generated

```
grid = new Slick.Grid("#sgrid", rows, columns, options);
grid.setCellCssStyles("highlight", cell_info_to_be_highlighted);
grid.render();
```

And this is the output of `console.log(JSON.stringify(cell_info_to_be_highlighted));`

```
{"29":{"column_3":"changed"},"33":{"column_3":"changed"},"34":{"column_3":"changed"},"35":{"column_3":"changed"},"36":{"column_3":"changed"},"37":{"column_3":"changed"},"38":{"column_3":"changed"},"39":{"column_3":"changed"}}
```

Now the grid is properly displayed but there is not highlighting at all. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

The problem was somewhere else

I was not setting the id of columns properly. Hence all the problems were happening. The id of the column should be the same thing that you give in cell_info_to_be_highlighted.

Comment: Try `grid.invalidateRows();` before `grid.setCellCssStyles()`

Comment: I'm having the same issue - did you get a fix Ranjith?

Comment: @Les yeah, my problem was elsewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that the "changed" CSS class is being applied properly, but the background property is ignored because the default has a higher level of specificity.  Try changing it to   `background: yellow!important`.